# paste() collapse with tabs

Tags: r, string, text

Is there a way to concatenate strings with tabs? I want to generate a tab separated file but using

```
paste(c("blah","blah"), collapse="\t")
```

gives

```
"blah\tblah"
```

using

```
paste(c("blah","blah"), sep='\t')
```

gives

```
"blah" "blah"
```

I want something to the effect of

```
"blah    blah"
```

where the entries are one string with the words separated by tabs.

Comment: If you wrap with `cat`, it gives the expected output i.e. `cat(paste(c('blah', 'blah'), collapse='\t'), '\n')`

Comment: @PRVS `sep` doesn't do anything unless `paste(..., sep=bah)` has multiple args in its `...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to spend time racking your brain on this.  Just stick four spaces in `collapse`.

```
paste(c("blah","blah"), collapse = "    ")
# [1] "blah    blah"
```

By the way, it would be fine to write to file the way you already have it.  If we do

```
writeLines(paste(c("blah", "blah"), collapse = "\t"), "blah.txt")
```

the file **blah.txt** looks like this

```
blah    blah
```

In fact, you could simplify it to take `paste()` out of the equation.

```
writeLines(c("blah", "blah"), sep = "\t")
# blah    blah
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how i could achieve the opposite i.e. go from "blah <tab>  blah" to ("blah","blah")?